# Reading xml from urls with ruby nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to parse a bunch of XML files. I am using Nokogiri, Ruby and XPath. But dont get any result. What are I am doing wrong, would be greatful for some tips or some code samples.

Example of the XML-file: xml-link

**HERE IS MY RUBY SCRIPT:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# parse the HTML document with all the links to the XML files.
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('link'))
# URLS - array
@urls = Array.new 
#Get all XML-urls and save them in urls-array
doc.xpath('//a/@href').each do |links|
  @urls << links.content
end

#LOCALITY array
@locality = Array.new
# loop all the url of the XML files
@urls.each do |url|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  # grab the content I want
  doc.xpath('//educationprovider//vcard//adr/locality').each do |locality_node| 
   # store it in locality array
    @locality << locality_node.content
  end
  # loop the the locality array and print it out
  (0..@locality.length - 1).each do |index|
    puts "LOCAL: #{@locality[index]}"
  end  
end
```

**EDIT:**
The problem was in xpath expression. The right expression was:
//educationprovider//vcard//adr//locality

Comment: You can't `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('link'))`, but you could `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com'))`. For future questions, anytime you want help with an XML or HTML issue we need to be able to access a sample of the data, or the live data. Trying to answer this question without it would have been nigh unto impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in xpath expression. 
The right expression was: //educationprovider//vcard//adr//locality